# Error Trying to copy a sharepoint file to DL

Tags: sharepoint-2010, azure-synapse

Hello could someone please help me on this,

I am trying to copy sharepoint files to my DL but it's not working I got this error

**{ "errorCode": "2200", "message": "ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithClientError,
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=Http request failed with client error, status code 403 Forbidden, please check your activity settings. If you configured a baseUrl that
*includes path, please make sure it ends with '/'.\nRequest URL:* ,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,
Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=System,'", "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Copy SharepointFile", "details": [] }**
[image]

Comment: This error massage indicates that sharepoint is rejecting ADF access. Please check that you have followed MS guide , the part about registering an application and giving it access to sharepoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#copy-file-from-sharepoint-online

Comment: That's whad had been done, for the API APP created I have aded file.read permission

Comment: make sure you did part 2 in the prerequisites - Grant SharePoint Online site permission. That was the issue in my case. Also check in the output that the created URL is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To copy data from SharePoint to azure data lake first you need to give permissions to the app by following below procedure:

register an app in azure and create client secret 1for that copy secret value, AppId, TenantId.

For granting permission open below url

```
https://[your_site_url]/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
```

you will get as below:

[image]

fill the above fields. Permission Request XML:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Read"/>
```

click on trust it.

[image]

After that create pipeline and create web activity with below URL format

```
URL: https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/[Tenant-ID]/tokens/OAuth/

Body: grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[Client-ID]@[Tenant-ID]&client_secret=[Client-Secret]&resource=00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/[Tenant-Name].sharepoint.com@[Tenant-ID]
```

Replace Tenant-ID , Client-Secret, Client-ID, Tenant-Name
with your details.

[image]

After success of web activity add copy data activity.
create linked services of http and data lake for.
HTTP linked service:

```
Base url: https://[site-url]/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('[relative-path-to-file]')/$value
```

[image]

Datalake linked service:

[image]

create dataset for source as below:

```
Additional headers: @{concat('Authorization: Bearer ', activity('<Web-activity-name>').output.access_token)}
```

[image]

Sink:

[image]
,
In my case I debug the pipeline without entering Additional headers I got below error:

[image]

After that I enter Additional headers and debug the pipeline, it executed successfully.

[image]

For more clarification you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites).

AFAIK for copy files from SharePoint to azure data lake when compare with Azure data factory or synapse Logic apps are better way. You can try with logic apps [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5893/transfer-files-from-sharepoint-to-blob-storage-with-azure-logic-apps/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have already put the header but got that error

Comment: Can you check [this](https://youtu.be/FFfNu3cI-uw) once?

Comment: I followed that video

Comment: I don't have the same error but I have new one ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithUnauthorizedError,
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=Http request failed with status code 401 Unauthorized,
 usually this is caused by invalid credentials,
 please check your activity settings.\nRequest URL "

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902968/azure-data-factory-401-error-when-calling-get-request-on-sharepoint-online-api) once.